# Team Foundation Service publishing to Azure with multiple branches

Tags: azure, tfs, publishing, azure-devops

I'm currently working with Team Foundation Service in combination with Windows Azure. I've created a Website in Azure and setup TFS publishing.

Everything is working perfectly except I was wondering how to configure different branches.

[This article](http://www.bradygaster.com/multiple-environments-with-windows-azure-web-sites) explains how you can use Git to configure different websites to point to different branches. It says:

> In this example, I’ll be using GitHub.com to manage my source code.
>   You don’t have to use GitHub.com for this, so if you’re new to Git
>   don’t freak out, you have other options like CodePlex, BitBucket, or
>   **TFS**. Heck, you could even automate an FTP deployment if you want to.

However, I can't find the branching option for my TFS publishing configuration. Am I missing something? Is this a Git only feature?

Comment: I know there's a way you could specify Visual Studio publishing profiles from within a TFS build. If you want to see some details on driving deployments to Windows Azure Web Sites with publishing profiles this post focuses on how that's possible. 

http://www.bradygaster.com/managing-multiple-windows-azure-web-site-environments-using-visual-studio-publishing-profiles

Comment: Ok thanks.. I've previously used the publish profiles and it is a solution.. However, the Git/Branch with automatic deploy is way nicer! I hope this is a feature they will add in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the web and having some contact with Microsoft I found the necessary configuration steps.

These are the things you have to do:

- Link the two websites to your team project
- Branch your code
- Adjust the workspace mappings on the build definition to the staging site to map the branch
- Change the solution to build property on the build definition for your staging site to point to the solution in your branch

I wrote a blog post about it that explains it in more detail: [Branches, Team Foundation Service and Azure Websites](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/11/branches-team-foundation-service-and.html)